# Vertical Align on Inline Blocks (middle not working)

Tags: css

I have 3 divs next to each other using a grid.
All the divs (the columns) are inline-blocks. I added 3 classes to control the vertical alignment of the divs (vtop, vmiddle, vbottom). The problem is, that vtop and vbottom work fine, but vmiddle shows no action.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-desktop-4 vmiddle">
        COLUMN 1<br/>
        Line 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-desktop-4">
        COLUMN 2<br/>
        Line 1<br/>
        Line 2<br/>
        Line 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-desktop-4 vbottom">
        COLUMN 3<br/>
        Line 1
    </div>
</div>
```

Do you have any idea why this is not working?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/marcbaur/5rg0rs3v/7/

Greets
Marc

Comment: Are you using Sass in your CSS? I don't see it included in the Fiddle as an external resource.

Comment: All need to have the property including the tallest div http://jsfiddle.net/5rg0rs3v/9/

Comment: Hi Danko. Thanks for the idea which actually works. But since the contents are generated dynamically I dont know which is the largest. Why does vertical-align:middle only works if it is set on the largest div?

Answer (score 0):

See: http://jsfiddle.net/5rg0rs3v/13/

First you should compile your less code into CSS.

Why the vertical alignment won't work will be explained among others at http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/ an solution can be found at: http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Firstly wrap you content in a additional div:

```
    <div class="col-desktop-4 vmiddle"><div>
        COLUMN 1<br/>
        Line 1</div>
    </div>
```

And than apply the css code like that shown below:

```
.vmiddle:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em; /* Adjusts for spacing */
}
.vmiddle {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```